# Who can help me understand this C++ programming project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

As I have been learning this week, by overloading standard operators on a class, we can exploit the intuition of the users of that class. By overloading an operator, we are really changing the way the compiler uses the operator based on its arguments.

Here is my project for this week:

Create a C++ program using Visual Studio where you design a 
“PhoneCall” class that holds a phone number to which a call is placed, the length of the call in minutes, and the rate charged per minute. Overload extraction and insertion operators for the class. In this program, overload the == operator to compare two PhoneCalls. Consider one PhoneCall to be equal to another if both calls are placed to the same number. Also, create a main() function that allows you to enter ten PhoneCalls into an array. If a PhoneCall has already been placed to a number, do not allow a second PhoneCall to the same number. Save the file as PhoneCall.cpp.

Compile this application using Visual Studio and run it to make sure it is error free.

The following is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

class PhoneCall { 
private: 
    string phonenumber; 
    double perminuterate; 
    double calldurationminutes; 
public: 
    bool operator==( const PhoneCall &n ) const; 
    friend ostream & operator<<( ostream &f, const PhoneCall &n ); 
    friend istream & operator>>( istream &f, PhoneCall &n ); 
 }; 
 bool PhoneCall::operator==( const PhoneCall &n ) const { 
    return phonenumber == n.phonenumber; 
 }; 
 ostream & operator<<( ostream &f, const PhoneCall &n ) { 
    f << "Phone number: " << n.phonenumber << 
         ", Duration: " << n.calldurationminutes << 
         " minutes, Rate: " << n.perminuterate << endl; 
 return f; 
 } 
 istream & operator>>( istream &f, PhoneCall &n ) { 
 f >> n.phonenumber; 
 f >> n.calldurationminutes; 
 f >> n.perminuterate; 
 return f; 
 } 
 int main( ) { 
 PhoneCall a[10]; 
 cout << "Enter 10 phone numbers, duration in minutes, and the per-minute rates." << 
     endl << "Separate each with a space and then hit enter to complete it." << endl; 
 for ( int i= 0; i < 10; ) { 
     cin >> a[i]; 
     int j; 
     for ( j= 0; j < i; ++j ) 
         if ( a[i] == a[j] ) { 
             cout << "Duplicate number information ignored. Try again." << endl; 
             break; 
         } 
     if ( j == i ) ++i; 
 } 
 for ( int i= 0; i < 10; ++i ) 
     cout << a[i];

 system("pause");
 return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: Microsoft Virtual Studio? :)

Comment: "I keep getting error messages" is totally meaningless unless you include those error messages. You have that information right in front of you; there's absolutely no excuse for not including it in your question. Please [edit] to do so, and indicate which lines are causing the errors. Including it makes your question clear, and you're asking us for free help solving your problem; please at least put some effort into providing the information for us.

Comment: Someone hasn't been paying attention in class...

Comment: You should probably revert the massive content edit you just made and post a different question instead. You've completely changed the question and invalidated the posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have many, many syntax errors in your program.

Where is `inFile` declared?

```
inFile = new StreamReader("name.txt", true);
```

You have a brace instead of a bracket on this line:

```
inFile = new StreamReader{"name.txt");
```

You are bitwise OR-EQUALING the string value on this line:

```
while ((inValue = inFile.ReadLine()) |= null)
```

Did you mean `!=`?